# Unable to read data from the transport connection: Stream Reader Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following code throws the error: 
*"Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed."-System.IO.IOException.*

This method receives a URL as parameter, execute it and gets response from webserver.


While reading the response by using a Stream, the line `liBytesRead = lStream.Read(lBytes, 0, 128);` inside while loop throws the quoted error.

```
public bool GetFromUrl(ref string psUrl, ref string rsResult, ref int piTimeoutSeconds)
{
  System.Text.StringBuilder lStringB = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

try {
    WebRequest lWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(psUrl);
    int liTimeout = piTimeoutSeconds * 1000;

    lWebRequest.Timeout = liTimeout;

    WebResponse lWebResponse = lWebRequest.GetResponse;
    Stream lStream = default(Stream);
    lStream = lWebResponse.GetResponseStream;

    byte[] lBytes = new byte[129];
    int liBytesRead = lStream.Read(lBytes, 0, 128);
    System.Text.Encoding lEncode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

    while (liBytesRead > 0) {
        lStringB.Append(lEncode.GetString(lBytes, 0, liBytesRead));
        liBytesRead = lStream.Read(lBytes, 0, 128);
    }
    lStream.Close();

    rsResult = lStringB.ToString();
    return true;
} catch (System.IO.IOException e) {
    rsResult = e.ToString();
    return false;
}
}
```

Any idea why it is happening.....

 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the webserver closing the connection prior to it being finished. 
Try with

```
HttpRequest.KeepAlive = false; 
HttpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
```

For more details please refer: http://sysrc.code4beer.org/2009/06/30/webrequest-unable-to-read-from-transport/